# Eclipse crashes in Cloudera quickstart VM with cairographics error

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, cloudera, eclipse-kepler, cloudera-quickstart-vm

Using Eclipse(Kepler) in Cloudera Quickstart VM v5.8.0.
Eclipse crashes randomly anytime during coding.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Unable to load 
graphics library
```

RAM allocation for VM = 10GB with video mem = 64MB
so should not be a low memory issue.

Has anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching and trials found solution for this issue.
Add below line to the end of eclipse.ini file, found in the eclipse folder.

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.cairoGraphics=false
```